# What files are in the virtual type scripts folder in visual studio

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When I read all the typescript VS tutorials they show only *.ts files within the scripts folder getting compiled to *.js files and moved to the wwwroot folder in asp.net core project.

But where are the .html,.css put? In the wwwroot directly? But then I have to sync my mind to 2 "project" solutions thats stupid.

Why not put all files in the scripts folder, but scripts does literally not mean html or css...

So can anyone tell me please what I am supposed to do here?

Comment: I just put my typescript files in the wwwroot folder. When I make a change and save them they are automatically compiled in the same path. Which tutorial are you following that does things differently?

Comment: I just do not understand that Microsoft excepts from me to have .ts files in scripts (single source of truth) and html+css files in the wwwroot. For .ts files its a temp dump (*.js) and for html+css files its the single source of truth. Thats totally annoying! Concerning typescript development visual studio is the worst I have seen inside visual studio! I am always scrolling up/down from scripts to wwwroot and back. Thats a total unproductive workflow.

Answer (score 0):

> I just do not understand that Microsoft excepts from me to have .ts files in scripts (single source of truth) and html+css files in the wwwroot. For .ts files its a temp dump (*.js) and for html+css files its the single source of truth

Microsoft doesn't expect anything from you. Users sometimes like to have *code* distant from *output* and so you *can* put ts in a `scripts` folder. You **don't need to** and can just keep it all in wwwroot.

Comment: I am confused. You say I can put .ts also in wwwroot? The drawback would be I publish my source .ts files to the server in the common publish process.

Comment: I found a sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1019920/Building-AngularJS-application-with-TypeScript-and having the .html files also in the scripts folder using a gulp html copy on build etc...the wwwroot is only a dump not more for me. I want a single source of truth for all kind of files, thats naturally.